# How to use BindableProberty directly inside ViewModelBase class from MVVMHelper

Tags: xamarin.forms

i think my problem is about misunderstanding OOP, when my class inherits BindableObject my code is working fine , but when my Class inherits MVVMhelper ViewModelBase the SetValue and GetValue is not defined in the current context,but i need to use bindable property in my view model

```
  public class TestViewModel : ViewModelBase
   { 
         public TestViewModel()
          {
          }
         public static readonly BindableProperty IsWorkingProperty =
          BindableProperty.Create(nameof(IsWorking), typeof(bool), 
          typeof(TestViewModel), default(bool));

         public bool IsWorking
         {
           get { return (bool)GetValue(IsWorkingProperty); }
           set { SetValue(IsWorkingProperty, value); }
         }
    }
```

Comment: ,I don't know what is the ViewModelbase, it is the class that implementing INotifyPropertychanged interface? But you want to create BindableProperty in TestViewModel, It should inherit BindableObject, refer to"https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.bindableobject.getvalue?view=xamarin-forms#Xamarin_Forms_BindableObject_GetValue_Xamarin_Forms_BindableProperty_

Comment: thanks, ViewModelBase is mvvm helper base view model which inherits from inotifypropertychanged, i say when i replase viewmodelbase with bindableobject every thing is working but i want to declare bindableproperty inside viewmodelbase

Answer (score 1):

> ViewModelBase is mvvm helper base view model which inherits from inotifypropertychanged, i say when i replase viewmodelbase with bindableobject every thing is working

you said that **ViewModelBase** is one class, implements **INotifyPropertyChanged** interface, you replace **ViewModelBase** with **BindableObject** class in your model, every thing works. Because **Bindableobject** is abstract class, also implements **INotifyPropertyChanged** interface, so you can use **BindableObject** implement notification function.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.bindableobject?view=xamarin-forms

> i want to declare bindableproperty inside viewmodelbase

I don't know why you want to declare bindableproperty in ViewModelBase, if you want to do this, you must inherit BindableObject class. GetValue(BindableProperty) and SetValue are used to access the values of properties that are implemented by a BindableProperty, these methods are adstract Bindableaobject method.

Because BindableObject class has implemented INotifyPropertyChanged, so you just make ViewModelBase inherit BindableObject.

Comment: Ok, thanks , i changed the method totally and get red of implementing new bindable property

Comment: @immortal, If my reply help your solve your issue, please remember to mark it as answer, thanks.